# Win32::Console: InputChar and codepage 65001

Tags: perl, winapi, input, console, codepages

When I run this script in a Windows console where the active codepage is 65001 `InputChar` returns `undef` if I enter an `ö` (U+00F6). Does this mean that `InputChar` doesn't work with `cp65001`?

```
#!perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.10.0;
use Devel::Peek; 
use Win32::Console;

my $in = Win32::Console->new( STD_INPUT_HANDLE );
$in->Mode( ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT );

my $char = $in->InputChar();
Dump $char;
say "{$char}";
```

---

```
C:>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

C:>perl.pl
SV = NULL(0x0) at 0x12b6fac
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY)
Use of uninitialized value $char in concatenation (.) or string at ... line 21.
{}
```

Comment: For people without the necessary language keyboard who wish to test this, hold down `Alt` and type `148` on the *keypad*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look inside sub [InputChar](https://metacpan.org/source/JDB/Win32-Console-0.10/Console.pm) you can see it uses [_ReadConsole](https://metacpan.org/source/JDB/Win32-Console-0.10/Console.xs) which doesn't do unicode (i think  char * isn't unicode)

It also doesn't do unicode because of the way  [ReadConsole function (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684958(v=vs.85).aspx)  is called, at least that is what documentation hints to me :)

**update:** OTOH, if I edit Win32-Console-0.10\Makefile.PL to add

```
DEFINE       => '  -DUNICODE   ',
```

and then recompile/reinstall Win32::Console, I can get `AöBöCöDö10` into the program using the following

```
my $chars = ShInputChar( $in, 10 );
sub ShInputChar {
    package Win32::Console;
    my($self, $number) = @_;
    return undef unless ref($self);

    $number = 1 unless defined($number);
    my $onumber = $number;
## double up or free to wrong pool, char versus wchar
    $number = 2 * $number;

    my $buffer = (" " x $number);
    my $readed = _ReadConsole($self->{'handle'}, $buffer, $number) ;
    my $err    = sprintf "ErrSet \$!(%d)(%s)\n\$^E(%d)(%s)\n", $!,$!,$^E,$^E;

    use Encode;
    $buffer = Encode::decode('UTF-16LE', $buffer );
    if ( $readed == $number  or $onumber == $readed ) {
        return $buffer;
    }
    else {
        warn "wanted $number but read $readed returning buffer anyway";
        return $buffer;
    }
}
```

You should report this to the author , hes more knowledgeable about win32

Answer (score -1):

I would be very cautious with [`libwin32`](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/libwin32-0.29/) (of which `Win32::Console` is a part) as it was last updated over six years ago, in the early days of Windows Vista.

You may want to try [`Win32::Unicode::Console`](https://metacpan.org/module/Win32::Unicode::Console) which has a very different API but is designed for your purpose.

Comment: I don't find there something like `InputChar`.